# C3536 cannot be used before it is initialized

Tags: c++, boost

I am working on an old source code project which originally was written using MSVC 2008 and Boost 1.42, today I'm trying to port this to MSVC 2017 with Boost 1.73

There are many issues to resolve, one of which is below:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3536   'binding': cannot be used before it is initialized  Process Control Service Group   processscope.cpp    197
```

The line that this occurs on:

```
auto binding = boost::bind(&IProcessChangeObserver::notify, _1, m_scope, change);
std::for_each(observers.begin(), observers.end(), binding);
```

Originally the assignment to binding was inline as the third parameter, it gives the same error.  I can see why this is a problem, I cannot see why it ever worked?

Is there another way to write the above without the triggering a warning?

I've tried replacing with a standard loop:

```
for( std::list<boost::intrusive_ptr<IProcessChangeObserver> >::iterator itProc=objservers.begin();
     itProc!=objservers.end(); itProc++ ) {
    boost:bind(&IProcessChangeObserver::notify, itProc, m_scope, change);
}
```

To be honest I'm not 100% sure if this is a like for like replacement?

Comment: About the loop replacement: no that just repeated binds a member function but never invokes it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The actual fix was just to change _1 to std::placeholders::_1

Answer (score 2):

I have a suspicion the real problem is with `binding` which is likely not correctly initialized. There's bound to be more compiler messages about that.

It could be because Boost Bind stopped putting the `_1` placeholders in the global namespace by default. You might detect this by adding `-DBOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS` to the compiler flags. However, heed the advice from the code:

```
BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE(
  "The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) "
  "in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use "
  "<boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, "
  "or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior."
)
```

---

### Minimal repro

See if you can reproduce with this minimal reproducer (I can't but I don't have access to the requisite versions ofr MSVC/Boost):

**[Live ON Coliru - GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f5605c06e03a20a)**

**[Live On Rextester - MSVC](https://rextester.com/RQFT95664)**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
using namespace boost::placeholders;
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ref_counter.hpp>
struct Scope {};
struct Change {};

namespace MyLib {
    struct IProcessChangeObserver
        : boost::intrusive_ref_counter<IProcessChangeObserver>
    {
        virtual ~IProcessChangeObserver() = default;
        virtual void notify(Scope, Change) = 0;
    };

    struct Obs1 : IProcessChangeObserver {
        void notify(Scope, Change) override { std::cout << "Obs1\n"; }
    };
    struct Obs2 : IProcessChangeObserver {
        void notify(Scope, Change) override { std::cout << "Obs2\n"; }
    };
}

using ObserverPtr = boost::intrusive_ptr<MyLib::IProcessChangeObserver>;

int main() {
    using namespace MyLib;
    std::list<ObserverPtr> observers {
        new Obs1(), new Obs2(), new Obs1(),
    };

    Scope m_scope;
    Change change;
    auto binding = boost::bind(&IProcessChangeObserver::notify, _1, m_scope, change);
    std::for_each(observers.begin(), observers.end(), binding);
}
```

Prints

```
Obs1
Obs2
Obs1
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, will be looking into this today.